# ajax url point to a php function in seperatet file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sql-delete

I'm having some problems with ajax (have never been working with it).
I would like to delete the selected row from the tabel without refreshing the page, and without creating a new file for the query. I'd like to keep all functions in the functions.php if possible?

I have 3 files here.

- index.php
- ajax.js
- functions.php

index file:

```
$res = articles($db);
   foreach($res as $res){
      $id = $res['article_id'];

    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
      echo "<input type=hidden" name='delete' value="<?php echo $id;?>">
      echo "<input type='submit' name='delete_article'>";
    echo "</form>";
      }
```

the ajax call

```
$.ajax({ url: 'HERE I WANT TO RUN THE DELETE FUNCTION FROM FUNCTIONS.PHP',
     data: {action: 'test'},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {
                  alert(output);
              }
});
```

the function

```
function delete_article($db){

$id = $_POST['delete'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM articles WHERE article_id = :article_id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':article_id',$id);
$stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Why it is so important that keep all functions in one file?

Comment: you don't "run functions" via ajax. the ajax call runs a SCRIPT, which can call your function. if you want the ajax call to do a delete option, then you have to write some code to get the target script call your delete stuff.

Comment: @Danijel it makes the whole project easier to look at, and if i need to edit it, then it's all in the same place

Comment: Here is one program that is easy to look and edit `<?='Hello World'?>`. I'm just kidding so don't be offended but separating functionality in different files can only make things cleaner and easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a good approach would be to use REQUEST_METHOD.

php

```
switch (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
    case "post":
        someFunctionToSave($_GET["postId"]);
        break;
    case "get":
        someFunctionToRetrieve($_GET["postId"]);
        break;
    case "delete":
        someFunctionToDelete($_GET["postId"]);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

js

```
function deletePost (id) {
  $.ajax({ url: 'function.php?postId=' + id,
    data: {},
    type: 'delete',
    success: function(data) {}
  })
}
function savePost (id) {
  $.ajax({ url: 'function.php?postId=' + id,
    data: {},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {}
  })
}
function getPost (id) {
  $.ajax({ url: 'function.php?postId=' + id,
    data: {},
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data) {}
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

True solution:

- build some action which are you can call from the browser, for example `yuorurl.com/post/delete/123`, 123 - your post id
- on server side create function which can handle this action (checking permissions, e.t.c), and returns `true` on success and `false` on fail.
- on client side, in your ajax handler remove post element on success

Example:

```
PHP

function delete($id) {
   $result = [];
   try {
      $this->yourPostService->delete($id); // handle your sql here
      $result = ['result' => true];
   } catch(Exception $e) {
      $result = ['result' => false, 'error' => $e->getMessage()];
   }
   echo json_encode($result);
   exit;
}

JS

$.ajax({ url: 'yourl/post/delete/'+id, // your post id
 data: {},
 type: 'post',
 success: function(data) {
              var data = $.parseJson(data);
              if(data.result) {
                 $('#post'+id).remove(); //your post element
              } else {
                 console.log(data.error)
              }
          }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({ url: 'FUNCTIONS.PHP',
     data: {action: 'delete', delete: '123'},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {alert(output);}
});
```

in function.php

```
if(isset($_POST['action'] && $_POST['action'] == 'delete')
    delete_article($db);
```

Comment: that is the way to post variable to the aajax page. in ur function u r getting `$_POST['delete']`. this delete needs to be passed here. `123` is the value for that `$_POST['delete']`. its a dummy value for ur example, u need to pass the `id` instead of `123` which u want to delete

Answer (score 0):

first, there are quite a few typos in your code. So you will need to fix them if anything is going to run at all. Keeping that in mind, here is a short revision of your code that should work. (I have not tested it).

I would advise using a Editor with a GUI that helps you identify issues with HTML and PHP coding.

Your Index File :

```
<?
$res = articles($db);
foreach ($res as $res) {
    $id = $res['article_id'];

    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<input type=hidden name='delete' id='article_id' value = '$id' >";
    echo "<input type='button' name='delete_article' onclick='delete_article(\"$id\")'>";
    echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

Your Javascript :

```
<script>
    function delete_article(articleId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'function.php',
            data: {
                action: 'test',
                article: articleId
            },
            type: 'post',
            success: function (output) {
                alert(output);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Your function.php

```
<?php
$action = (isset($_POST['action'])) ? $_POST['action'] : false;
switch (strtolower($action)) {
    case "test":
        /* create your $db connection */
        delete_article($db);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
echo "OK";
exit;

function delete_article($db){

    $id = $_POST['delete'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM articles WHERE article_id = :article_id";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':article_id',$id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```